# How can I work with multiple values using ->?

Tags: perl

I am new to Perl and made some changes to an existing script, but I am not sure if this a right usage in Perl. In C# we do things differently, so is the code sample below correct?

```
$group->{$type}{class} = 1;
```

The code I added is

```
 $group->{$type}{class} = 1;
 $group->{$name}{port} = 1;
```

Is this right? Can $group point to both type and name. I tried this with a sample Perl script and it seemed to set and return '1' correctly. But I am not sure if this is how I should do this.

Comment: give more details and a simple example of what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that looks correct. You are building a complex data structure, specifically a [hash of hashes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#HASHES-OF-HASHES) (HoH). The `group` hash has two keys, `$type` and `$name`. The `$type` subhash has one key, `class`. The `$name` subhash has one key, `port`. It looks like this, roughly, if you dumped it or declared it all at once:

```
$group = {
  $type => {
    class => 1
  },
  $name => {
    port => 1
  }
}
```

Of course, `$type` and `$name` will evaluate to whatever they're set to. It won't store the reference in the hash.

Answer (score 2):

Um ... this is perl.  If it works, it's right.  But, to your question.  In your code `$group` is a reference to a hash (maybe called a `dictionary` in c#). I think you are probably looking for this:

```
my $group={}; # make the ref
my @types = ('hot','cold','warm');   # make some types
my @names = ('sink','bath','drain'); # and some names

foreach my $type (@types){
    $group->{'type'}->{$type}++; # add a new $type to the "type" sub hash
}

foreach my $name (@names){
    $group->{'name'}->{$name}++; # add a new $nameto the "name" sub hash
}
```

Now cycle through the types for example:

```
foreach my $typeKey (keys %{$group->{'type'}}){
    print "type is " . $typeKey; # this is from the @types array
    print ", value = " . $group->{'type'}->{$typeKey}; # this would be 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. I learn new things everyday :)